# Call of boost::compute::sort() with zip iterators delivers build errors

Tags: c++, boost, boost-compute

I have a problem building a program that makes use of the Boost.Compute library.
I use two `zip_iterator`s consisting out of a tuple of two float iterators each 
to sort two float-vectors with the `boost::compute::sort()` function.
My code (both `compute::vector`s have been filled with float values before):

```
typedef compute::vector<float>::iterator Float_Iterator;
typedef boost::tuple<Float_Iterator, Float_Iterator> Sort_Tuple;
typedef compute::zip_iterator<Sort_Tuple> Sort_Iterator;

Sort_Iterator first_sort = compute::make_zip_iterator
(boost::make_tuple(d_x.begin(), d_y.begin()));
Sort_Iterator last_sort = compute::make_zip_iterator
(boost::make_tuple(d_x.end(), d_y.end()));

BOOST_COMPUTE_FUNCTION(bool, compare, (const boost::tuple<float, float> p1, const boost::tuple<float, float> p2),
{
    return boost_tuple_get(p1, 0) < boost_tuple_get(p2, 0);
}
);

compute::sort(first_sort, last_sort, compare, queue);
```

When compiling this, I receive:

```
error C2782: 'void   boost::compute::detail::dispatch_merge_blocks(Iterator,Iterator,Compare,size_t,c onst size_t,const size_t,const size_t,boost::compute::command_queue &)' :   **template parameter 'Iterator' is ambiguous**
          c:\local\boost_1_62_0\boost\compute\algorithm\detail\merge_sort_on_cpu.hpp(129)     : see declaration of 'boost::compute::detail::dispatch_merge_blocks'
          could be **'Sort_Iterator'
 or       'boost::compute::buffer_iterator<T>'**
          with
          [
              T=value_type
          ]
```

As you can see in my code, I call the function with two `Sort_Iterator`s I have declared before. Both arguments have the same type, so why should the compiler assume any ambiguity? I don't get this.

However, if I try to explicitly type cast the function arguments, like

```
compute::sort((Sort_Iterator)first_sort, (Sort_Iterator)last_sort, compare,    queue);
```

the latter part of the error message changes to:

```
could be **'boost::compute::zip_iterator<Sort_Tuple>'
or       'boost::compute::buffer_iterator<T>'**
with
[
     T=value_type
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Even if your code compiled, you wouldn't be able to sort zip iterators: they are read-only. You must sort a vector of tuples instead.

Regarding the `Iterator` ambiguity, the compiler isn't referring to the types *you* are passing, but to the `Iterator` of some function much deeper in the call chain:

```
template<class Iterator, class Compare>
inline void dispatch_merge_blocks(Iterator first, Iterator result, /* ... /);
```

It is called this way:

```
dispatch_merge_blocks(first, temp.begin(), /* ... */);
dispatch_merge_blocks(temp.begin(), first, /* ... */);
```

Here, `first` is the `Iterator` you passed in, of type:

```
zip_iterator<tuple<buffer_iterator<float>, buffer_iterator<float>>>
```

And `temp.begin()` is...

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;

// temporary buffer for merge result
vector<value_type> temp(count, context);
```

a `vector<tuple<float, float>>::iterator`<sup>**(1)**</sup>. The compiler sees two different types for the same template parameter, and hence deduction fails.

Additionally, further in the call chain appears the following function:

```
template<class Iterator, class Compare>
inline void merge_blocks(Iterator first, Iterator result, /* ... */)
{
    // dummy iterator as it's not sort by key
    Iterator dummy;
    merge_blocks(first, dummy, result, dummy, /* ... */);
}
```

Note the line: `Iterator dummy;`. That fails to compile because `zip_iterator` has no default constructor, so template instantiation fails and the whole thing fails to compile.

**(1)**: I am not entirely sure how `value_type` ends up being deduced as `tuple<float, float>`, and going through the endless layers of templates is giving me a mild headache, but this is what is happening, essentially.

Comment: Thank you! But one question remains: why would it be a problem to pass read only zip_iterators? I dont want to get the zip_iterators sorted, but the float vectors they point at (via the tuple of iteratos construct). So the value of the zip_iterators themselves should not be altered during sort(), should they?

Comment: The way the [OpenCL codegen for zip iterators is currently implemented](https://github.com/boostorg/compute/blob/master/include/boost/compute/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp#L107) in Boost Compute simply prevents assignment from working, regrettably. I wonder if this could be fixed and at what cost.